# How to access ElementName of Dynamic controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl which have dynamically created Buttons

```
<ItemsControl>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Button>
   </Button>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I am trying to display a Popup when hovering over one of these buttons, but seeing that the buttons are generic, I dont know the name of the button. Like this:

```
 <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=buttonName}" 
  IsOpen ="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=buttonName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

How can I achieve opening the Popup and set the PlacementTarget of the Button I'm hovering over??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place popup inside datatemplate as well:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Button x:Name="buttonName"/>
                <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=buttonName}" IsOpen="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=buttonName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```